# Data from Firebase undefined in React

Tags: mongodb, reactjs, firebase, state

I'm playing with Firebase as an alternative to a local Mongo store, for the time being.

I've followed various tutorials, however they are all for older versions of ES6. I've tried to tweak them to v14 and ES6 but, well, no errors but no data!

Some code:

```
var Rebase = require('re-base');
var base = Rebase.createClass('https://reactathon.firebaseio.com/days');

...

componentDidMount() {
        console.log('ExampleComponent Mounted');
        base.bindToState('days', {
            context: this,
            state: 'days',
            asArray: true
        });
        console.log(this.state.days[0]);
    }
```

The console simply logs undefined. I've tried the base URL with and without /days. I've tried getting the data as an object instead of an array. I have a feeling I'm simply pointing at the wrong thing.

Any thoughts?

Cheers.

Comment: What does the data at /days look like?

Comment: Oh, I see the problem. The data won't load immediately. For testing purposes, wrap the log in a three second timeout. Or better yet, move the log to your render method. The component will re—render once the data is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

bindToState is an asynchronous method so it's going to take some time to set up that listener. You're logging before the listener has been set up. As Jacob mentioned in his comment, move your log to your render method and then once your state is bound to Firebase your component will re render and you should see your data.